# Text stuck behind div

Tags: html, css

I have text that is currently stuck behind a div with a slightly transparent background and cannot seem to get it to come forwards.

I have tried changing the position in "image-text" but they all send it to the very back.

```css
    .top-container
    {
    
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
    }
    
    /*background image*/
    .desk
    {
    
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     filter: blur(5px);
    }
    
    
    .imagetext
    {
    
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 50%;
     padding-left: 30%;
     padding-right: 30%; 
     margin-left: 15%;
     translate: (-50%. -50%);
     background-color: grey;
     opacity: 0.3;
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px solid white;
     color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="top-container">
     <img src="images/desk.jpg" alt="Desk" class="desk">
      <div class="imagetext">
       <h2>text header</h2>
       <p>sadfd hdsfsaf ssds</p>
       <p>fhr fhswodd hwlfjhs w ds</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use z-index for that. z-index:0; for background and z-index:1; for text.

Comment: html added, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

As Architect said, you need to add a z-index value (see Snippit below)

```css
.top-container
{

    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

/*background image*/
.desk
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: blur(5px);
}


.imagetext
{

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    padding-left: 30%;
    padding-right: 30%; 
    margin-left: 15%;
    translate: (-50%. -50%);
    background-color: grey;
    opacity: 0.3;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    z-index:1; /* <<=======   Just add this */
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/300" alt="Desk" class="desk">
    <div class="imagetext">
        <h2>text header</h2>
        <p>sadfd hdsfsaf ssds</p>
        <p>fhr fhswodd hwlfjhs w ds</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, you really should read these articles about how to create a full-page background image:

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/backgrounds-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices-2/